# How to detect if the consuming application is running next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am building a component library which can be used in vanilla react or next js applications.

When a component is installed, how can I detect if the component is being used in next js context?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window object to figure this out.

[image]

Hope this helps,

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Window.next, you can also search for "__next" in HTML source using Inspect element. Next apps have this div in their app so if you can see that that means its on NEXTJS.